# Shipping CoreData App with Populated Table

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, deployment

I have a CoreData app with a single table that was populated from a text file. I have a routine in testing that initializes the table from the text file, but I would prefer to ship the app with the data already in place, and not have an initialization process have to happen.

I suspect that I would need to include the database table with the app, but I don't know how to do this with it populated. Clearly, there is a table there, but when the app goes out in TestFlight (which is where we are now), the table is empty.

What's the best way to avoid this initialization process, and ship the app with data?

Comment: Please provide the code that initializes your persistent store.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you mean a Core Data persistent store (Core Data doesn't have tables), here's an approach I've used in the past.

Create the persistent store in your app on the Simulator (or even on device), using the same code that you're using to create it while testing. Find that file on your Mac, or extract it from your device. You now have a (probably SQLite) file that contains your initial data.

Now add that file to your .xcodeproj as a resource. When you build your app you'll now include that initialization data as part of the bundle, and can search for it at launch.

Here's sample code for a static store. If you want to be able to update it, you'll have more work to do to initialize the live store from the static store.

```
    let persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "XYZZY")
    let storeURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "XYZZY", ofType: "sqlite")!)
    let psDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)
    psDescription.setOption(true as NSObject, forKey: NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption)
    persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions = [psDescription]
    persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores() { (description, error) in
        if let error = error {
            fatalError("Failed to load Core Data stack: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

If the file is large, you'll probably want to perform a vacuum on it when you create it. At that point it's worth having a separate Mac program that creates the initial persistent store from your text file.

Here's a way to find the SQLite file from your Mac importer:

```
    if let cdFolder = self.importer.datastoreURL()?.path {
        print("open", cdFolder)
        NSWorkspace.shared.openFile(cdFolder)
    }

func datastoreURL() -> URL? {
    if let cdFolder = persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions[0].url?.deletingLastPathComponent() {
        return cdFolder
    }
    return nil
}
```

which gives you a line on the console that you can copy/paste in Terminal.

Comment: Thanks, Hal, I'll give that a try.

Comment: An upvote or accepted answer is better than a thank you comment.

Comment: but until I've verified the idea, I'm not likely to do either. FYI, I'm located in S.E. Asia, so a 36 hour turn around cycle on messages from people in N America is the norm. It's a big world.